# Selecting Audio Files Using Intent.createChooser not working with all phones

Tags: android

I am nearing completion of a project I am working on using Android, but ran into a little bump in the road when we got a new device to test our application with.

I am programming using Android 1.6 and my two devices are:

HTC Incredible - Verizon (Android 2.2)
Samsung Galaxy S - T-Mobile (Android 2.1 update 1)

One part of the application allows the user to select a recorded audio file using:

```
// Select a recording
i = new Intent();           
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
i.setType("audio/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select audio file"), Enums.REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_ATTACHMENT);
```

And will call onActivityResult after the selection is made.

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && Enums.REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_ATTACHMENT == requestCode)) 
{
    // do something here
}
else
{
    //ResultCode comes back as RESULT_CANCELED
}
```

This works fine on the device I programmed my original application on (HTC Incredible - Verizon).

However, when using the Samsung Galaxy S (T-Mobile), the first select dialog opens (Music Player | Voice Recorder) but from there nothing really works.

If I select Music Player, none of my recordings are listed (on HTC, I can pick my recordings or music tracks that shipped with my phone).

If I select Voice Recorder, it returns to my onActivityResult method with result code RESULT_CANCELED and displays a toast message saying "Message file limit reached".

Can anyone give some insight on this? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Galaxy S audio subsystem is notoriously broken in 2.1. For instance, Skype does not work on these devices. I've found that 2.2 fixes a lot of the issues.

One thing you can experiment with is calling [AudioManager.setMode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setMode%28int%29) to MODE_IN_CALL before recording. Also, you might look at some open source code to see if they've solved this particular issue (see for instance [Ringdroid](http://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/)).

There's lots of information about how the Galaxy S audio doesn't work according to spec out there ([for instance the speakerphone routing is very broken](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/issues/detail?id=371&q=galaxy%20speaker)).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I was holding out to see if there are any other comments, but I will mark this as answered. I cannot for the life of me upgrade the firmware on my Galaxy S, seeing that you have to use Kies to do so, and I don't want to jailbreak the phone in any way. The Kies software (2.0) does not seem to support the phone...

Comment: how to set Mode to AudioManager